# ARMA GARCH with multiple external regressor in mean model in R

Tags: r, regression

I was using the `rugarch` package to fit an `ARMA-GARCH` model with multiple external regressors. But there is an error message that says:

```
Error in svd(na.omit(xreg)) : a dimension is zero
```

I'm wondering what is causing this error. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, it is easier for others to help you if they can copy/paste your code, run it, and reproduce your problem. See [how to write a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

1. `testdata_1` should be in matrix format.
2. There should be no Na's
3. Check if there's data inside `testdata_1[,-c(1:2)]`